# Directory only creates when run on localhost

Tags: java, eclipse

Good day! I was just wondering why my codes on creating directory only works on localhost. When the project deployed to live server and access on the client-side, it does not work anymore.

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents";
        path += File.separator + ("CUSTOM_FOLDER");
        File customDir = new File(path);
        customDir.mkdirs();
```

**UPDATE:**

I just modified my code to

```
File outReportDir = new File("C:/CUSTOM_FOLDER");
        outReportDir.mkdir();
```

and it creates the folder now. Problem is when the client clicks the button to create folder, the folder creates on the C:\ of the server where the war file is placed, not on the user's own C:\ Why is it?  Thanks for the time.

Comment: Check if you have proper permissions to create Directory on server

Comment: Yes I have sir. Please help me with my update. Thanks

Comment: what is final value of "path" variable on server side?

Comment: i guess it should be something like "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\CUSTOM_FOLDER" this and not "C:/CUSTOM_FOLDER"

Comment: On my first code, it's "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\CUSTOM_FOLDER". It does not work when I deployed it. But second code works and it creates "C:/CUSTOM_FOLDER" but only on the server directory.